# Javascript Show hide variable for form

Tags: javascript

Here is the code I am having trouble with everyone. This is what I have been working on for 8 hours since I do not know js. I got most of this from the w3school.com site and just have been trying to piece everything together. ugh please help

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var stringToMatch = 'christopher',  
input = document.getElementById('text'),  
div = document.getElementById('divColor1');  

 function toggle (switchElement){  
 if (this.value == stringToMatch){  
    div.style.display = 'block';  
}  
else {  
    div.style.display = 'none';  
}  
};?  
 </script>


 <!--This is the start of the code which i want to appear--> 
 <h3>Coupon Redeem</h3> 
 <form action="test" method="post"> 
Please type in the Coupon Code you have recieved: 
 <form id='coupon' onChange="javascript: ShowMenu(document.getElementById('text').value,'divColor1');">  
<input id="text" type="text"> 
<input type="button" id="text" value="Redeem" onClick="toggle(this)" /> 
</form>
 <!--This is the start of the hidden field that i want to appear when the coupon code is entered     correctly--> 
<div id="divColor1" style="display:none;"> 
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post"> 
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick"> 
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="asjsanxci"> 

  <input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Tokens">Tokens 
    <select name="os0"> 
  <o ption value="5 tokens">5 tokens$5.00 USD</option> 
 <option value="10 tokens">10 tokens$10.00 USD</option> 
 <option value="15 tokens">15 tokens$13.00 USD</option> 
 <option value="20 tokens">20 tokens$18.00 USD</option> 
 <option value="25 tokens">25 tokens$23.00 USD</option> 
 <option value="30 tokens">30 tokens$27.00 USD</option> 
 <option value="35 tokens">35 tokens$33.00 USD</option> 
 <option value="40 tokens">40 tokens$38.00 USD</option> 
  <option value="50 tokens">50 tokens$45.00 USD</option> 
 </select>  
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
<input type="hidden" name="on1" value="Username Verification">Username Verification 
 <input type="text" name="os1" maxlength="200"> 
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD"> 
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_SM.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!"> 
</form> 
</div> 

<br> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code has a syntax error

```
<div id="divColor1" style="displayed:none"
```

change that to

```
<div id="divColor1" style="display:none;">
```

also some other bugs that i found

```
<form id='coupon' onChange="javascript: ShowMenu(document.getElementById('text').var,'divColor1',);">
```

your ShowMenu is missing a variable, and another syntax error ***document.getElementById('text').var***

> >

```
<form id='coupon' 
    onChange="javascript: ShowMenu(document.getElementById('text').value,'divColor1');">
```

*Update*
I have made some changes to your code. you can see the working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/RTpmT/)

Updated code

```
<script>
var stringToMatch = 'christopher';  
function toggle (){  
 var input = document.getElementById('text').value; 

 if (input == stringToMatch){ 
    document.getElementById('divColor1').style.display = 'block';  
}  
else {  
   document.getElementById('divColor1').style.display = 'none';  
}  
};​
</script>

 <!--This is the start of the code which i want to appear--> 
 <h3>Coupon Redeem</h3> 
 <form action="test" method="post"> 
Please type in the Coupon Code you have recieved: 
 <form id='coupon' onChange="javascript: ShowMenu(document.getElementById('text').value,'divColor1');">  
<input id="text" type="text"> 
<input type="button" id="text" value="Redeem" onClick="toggle()" /> 
</form>
 <!--This is the start of the hidden field that i want to appear when the coupon code is entered     correctly--> 
<div id="divColor1" style="display:none;"> 
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post"> 
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick"> 
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="asjsanxci"> 

  <input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Tokens">Tokens 
    <select name="os0"> 
  <o ption value="5 tokens">5 tokens$5.00 USD</option> 
 <option value="10 tokens">10 tokens$10.00 USD</option> 
 <option value="15 tokens">15 tokens$13.00 USD</option> 
 <option value="20 tokens">20 tokens$18.00 USD</option> 
 <option value="25 tokens">25 tokens$23.00 USD</option> 
 <option value="30 tokens">30 tokens$27.00 USD</option> 
 <option value="35 tokens">35 tokens$33.00 USD</option> 
 <option value="40 tokens">40 tokens$38.00 USD</option> 
  <option value="50 tokens">50 tokens$45.00 USD</option> 
 </select>  
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
<input type="hidden" name="on1" value="Username Verification">Username Verification 
 <input type="text" name="os1" maxlength="200"> 
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD"> 
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_SM.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!"> 
</form> 
</div> 

<br> 
</form> ​
```

Comment: Ive been messing with code, since I have no variable in the javascript of ShowMenu, so i took that out. here is what i have so far...
    <h3>Coupon Redeem</h3> 
    <form method="post" form id="coupon" onChange="javascript:(document.getElementById('text').value,'divColor1');"> 
    Please type in the Coupon Code you have recieved:  

    <input id="text" type="text">
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="javascript:(document.getElementById('divColor1');"> 
    </form>

Comment: @nextlevelgamingCO have you made all the necessary changes mentioned by blueiur and me..if so update your code

Comment: @nextlevelgamingCO your code still has lots of bugs..i have made some changes..check my answer and see if it works.. i also have put jsfiddle link

Comment: Sibu i see that you have it working. but sadly testing it in coffeecup editor it seems to hate me or something haha. I put the javascript in the head tags correct? then the rest in html?

Comment: also I am using IE. could this be the problem.

Comment: oh another thing Sibu I WANT to give you credit the code. So in id like to make a //copyright Sibu or whatever you'd like just need to know exactly what.

Comment: wow im writing alot. ok so Sibu fixed error in the script you gave me. i guess after reading what i have it pays off. I dont know if it was a syntax error but }   
else {   
   document.getElementById('divColor1').style.display = 'none';   
}   
};​ 
</script>
the ; at the second bracket had to be removed and code works perfectly

Comment: @nextlevelgamingCO i am glad that i could help you :-)

Comment: would u like a created by part in the code? and i am glad as well. it was frustrating me that you got it to work and i couldnt, then realizing some of the tips and lessons ive learned was that of the closing bracket and semi colon haha its funny how one character destroyed everything. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

fix the code

```
displayed:none => display:none

var input = document.getElementById('text'); 
// your html don't have id='text' 

<input type="text"> => <input id='text' type="text">
```

you have to fix two problem then

it works!

good luck.

Comment: my bad, i was fixing the code on here from my editor, and i wrote displayed. thank you for pointing out. but yes it says display just not working at all.

Comment: you'r code have two problem one is display and two is id text field

Comment: ok so still not working exactly yet. Do you think my submit button is in wrong place? also the ShowMenu what do i do with that??